# jax rs redirecting git clone

Tags: java, git, jax-rs

So either I'm using the wrong termanology or i have just thought about my structure all wrong!

But my question / issue, I got a jax rs server running where i can handle of course CRUD requests and do some awesome magic to return data. But right now I'm trying to redirect or return a git clone request.

So i got git repositories that are not on the same place as the corresponding URL so i need to redirect it.

Example request would be: http://localhost:8080/repo/clone/{test}

Then the repository named "test" is somewhere like C:/.../../repos/{test}, is there a way and if so, how do i redirect that request to clone that specific repository?

Currently i can't even grab the git request (tried with @GET etc) and get stuck with a debugger.

**Edit 1**

Tried to produce a stream (MediaType stream) for the folder but it results in git having issues with SSL when trying to clone. (Only happends with HTTPS, still can't get a breakpoint working with HTTP)